# how to get response from async query for kdb

Tags: kdb

when I send a query to kdb in async method. I can't get any response, who can help me? BTW, C++ interface is used. I use k(handle, (S)0); to get response.

Comment: Please provide your c++ code and q function you're calling.

Comment: first, I use k(-handle, "select from table", K(0)); to query data. then I use k(handle, (S)0); ,try to receive data. But , I get nothing.

Comment: does your q session send the result back asyncly after the async msg is processed? That might be the issue.

Comment: I don't know how to see whether kdb send out result. can you tell me?

Comment: I confirmed that kdb don't send response back. "select from table" was sent to kdb in async method. is there any way to know whether kdb get this request?

Comment: yup, you need to modify the async message handler function `.z.ps` on the q session. I suggest something like `.z.ps:{show(.z.p;x);neg[.z.w]@[value;x;{"error: ",x}]}`. This is just showing you at what time what msg is received, process the msg with protected execution and send the result back asyncly.

Answer (score 4):

Generally asynchronous call does not return any result .

Check these pages:

http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals/i_o#Asynchronous_Messages

http://code.kx.com/wiki/Startingkdbplus/ipc

Following wiki has information for C++ Api call: 
http://code.kx.com/q//interfaces/c-client-for-q/

It says: If the handle is <0, this is for async messaging, and the return value can be either 0 (network error) or non-zero (ok). This result should NOT be passed to r0(r).

Comment: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/InterfacingWithC#Callbacks shows that user can use "r = k(c,(S)0); // read incoming asynch" to get a async response, I think. But , I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this google forum might help you to get a bit further:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/personal-kdbplus/m_dgucgAUpU